# Для чего используются сигнатуры классов, вроде Name<T, Q extends Name<T, Q>>

Tags: java

Для чего используются сигнатуры классов, вроде `Name<T, Q extends Name<T, Q>>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Такая конструкция позволяет из класса родителя возвращать тип потомка. Поясню на примере.

Есть два класса:

```
static class C<T> {
    public C<T> firstMethod() {
        return this;
    }
}

static class D<T> extends C<T> {
    public D<T> secondMethod() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Мы можем легко написать следующее:

```
new D<>().secondMethod().firstMethod();
```

Но обратное не получится сделать:

```
new D<>().firstMethod().secondMethod();
```

Т.к. в классе `C` в методе возвращается объект типа `C`, а в нем не определен `secondMethod`.

Для избежания подобной ситуации, пишут следующее:

```
static class A<T extends A<T>> {
    public T value;

    public T firstMethod() {
        return value;
    }
}

static class B<T> extends A<B<T>> {
    public B<T> secondMethod() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Это позволяет писать:

```
new B<>().firstMethod().secondMethod();
new B<>().secondMethod().firstMethod();
```